# angular view not updating when scope changes in controller (after form submit)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm very new to angular so I may be going about this all wrong but here goes.  I have a form

```
<form name="search_form" novalidate ng-submit="searchForm(search_form.$valid)" >
  <div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="formcontainer">What to eat?</div>
    <div class="formcontainer"><input type="text" name="food_type" ng-model="food_type" placeholder="Enter a search term" required></div>
    <div class="formcontainer">Where to look?</div>
    <div class="formcontainer">  <input type="text" name="cityname" ng-model="trader.cityname" value="cityname"  googleplace="" placeholder="Enter a location" required>
  </div>

  <div class="formcontainer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-main2" >Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

that when I submit I want to grab the results based on the location I get from google and display them in a new view

```
myControllers.controller('SearchCtrl',['$scope','Search','$location', function ($scope,Search,$location) {

  $scope.setSearchLocation = function(place){

    $scope.lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    $scope.lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
  }

  $scope.searchForm = function() {
    // check to make sure the form is valid
    if (!$scope.search_form.$valid) {
      alert('Please fill out all fields');
    }
    else{
      $scope.results = Search.do_search($scope.lat,$scope.lng);
      $location.path('search-results');
    }
  };   

}])
.directive('googleplace', function() {
  return {
    require : 'ngModel',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
      var options = {
          types : [],
      };
      scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0],options);

      google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed',function() {
        var place = scope.gPlace.getPlace();
        scope.setSearchLocation(place);
        scope.$apply(function() {
          model.$setViewValue(element.val());  
        });
      });
    },

  };
});
```

everything works as expected except the view does not update in the results view.  If I set the $scope.results out side the searchForm() function everything renders properly.  I realize this is because it exists before the page renders, just saying that part works.

when I try $scope.$apply() it says already in progress

```
<div id="results-container" ng-repeat="result in results">
        <div id="picbox"><img src="../images/test.jpg" alt="" "/></div>
          <div id="addressinfo">
            <h4>John's Restaurant  </h4>
            <p>123 York Street, Toronto ON <br>
              <span id="type">#
            Burgers, #Poutine</span></p>
          </div>
          <div id="location">4.2m<br>
            <img src="../images/heart.png" width="86" height="76" alt=""/><br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a problem right now but the directive is `ng-submit`, not `ng-Submit`

Comment: strange, not sure why that got capitalized here but it's lowercase on my screen.  So no that's not the issue.  The form submits fine.

Comment: I don't understand the intention of `$location.path('search-results')`.
Let us know more detail of your html structure.
Does the element of `div#results-container` exists on the same html with the element of `form[name=search_form]`?

Comment: My intention was to switch between two different templates the first being search.html which is the first block.  The user fills out the form, submits it.  The data is collected then the search-results.html template is loaded (the second html block).  I did try it in the same html file but it still didn't update.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. One more quastion. Both of templates use `SearchCtrl` as controller?

Comment: yes ng-controller="SearchCtrl" is the same in both

Comment: I got it. The problem seems that you call `$location.path`. When you call `$location.path`, $scope object of SearchCtrl is initialized.

Comment: ahh, that makes sense.  From what google is telling me I should be looking at  ng-include https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude so I can avoid $route all together.  I'll give that a shot.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `$location.path(...)`, $scope object of controller is always initialized.

My suggestion is ...

1. write the element of `div#results-container` on the same template where `form[name=search_form]` exists.
2. remove `$location.path('search-results');`

I hope this could help you.